# How do i setup (''transform") turtle to be another turtle in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

Im trying to use `set breed otherTurtleName 1`, but then i got error: 'solitario 1 is not a SOCIAL, 
error while solitario 0 running SOCIAL'
Example:

```
breed[sociais social]
breed[solitarios solitario]
(...)
    ask solitario 
    [
      (...)
      ifelse [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = yellow
      [
        set breed social 1 
      ]
      (...)
    ]
```

Comment: Try dropping the "1" and just use:

"set breed social"

Comment: Solved by dropping "1" and write sociais instead of social!